# What's the difference between ps | wc and ps r | wc in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to figure out what's the difference between

```
ps | wc
```

and

```
ps r | wc
```

Comment: You can use `man <package>` to understand more about a linux command. In this case `man ps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux the `|` pipe character issues the output of one command to the input of another. In this case `ps` output is sent to `wc`. So the difference in the two commands is really the difference between `ps` and `ps r`.

You can issue these commands separately and see the difference in output. You can also view the manpage for the `ps` command with `man ps` where you will find:

> r       Restrict the selection to only running processes.

So, the difference is that one counts the number of processes for the user, while the other counts only the running processes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID (euid=EUID) as the current user and associated with the same terminal as the invoker.

By specifying the 'r', you are restricting it to only running processes.

By piping it through to wc, you get the newline, word, and byte counts respectively.